# Angular Material Button background color not changing on applying css

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am developing a sample project in Angular 13 in which I have used Angular Material theme. In of the components I have used material buttons for logout confirmation dialog window and **I have changed the button background color to white in css but when i run the project it still shows the default grey color even after applying css**. Is there any way to force change the angular material colors because the one I have used is not working.

**Below are the code files for better understanding**

**logout-dialog.component.html**

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title class="logout-heading">Logout</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p class="message">Are you sure you want to logout ?</p>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions class="buttons-div">
  <button mat-button class="cancel" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button> //THIS BUTTON SHOULD HAVE WHITE BACKGROUND
  <button mat-button class="logout" (click)="logout()">Ok</button>
</div>
```

**logout-dialog.component.css**

```
.cancel {
  border: 1px solid #3f51b5;
  color: #3f51b5;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

**Image**
[image: Button still have grey color after applying css]

**Any solution please ?**

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the style on your `styles.css` file

Comment: Hi Kibe M.C I tried placing it in style.css but doesn't work

Comment: Try inspecting that particular element by pressing ```ctrl```+```shift```+```i``` on your browser, and applying your CSS on it.

Comment: Hi Kibé M.C  , I tried inspecting it, it shows the applied color in css but not on browser

Answer (score 0):

can you try with `inline-css`

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title class="logout-heading">Logout</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p class="message">Are you sure you want to logout ?</p>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions class="buttons-div">
  <button style="background-color: #fff !important;" mat-button class="cancel" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>  //my changes
  <button mat-button class="logout" (click)="logout()">Ok</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Dako patel inline css applied but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using `::ng-deep` selector

```
::ng-deep button.cancel {
  border: 1px solid #3f51b5;
  color: #3f51b5;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi Farith Adnan, I tried but it didn't work though